# Using VBA to save excel file as pdf to local drive

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am pretty new to VBA, so appreciate any help you can give. Something is wrong with my code below and I have been googling for a while to try and work out. I have an excel worksheet that I am trying to get VBA to:
1. Create a PDF using Cell C7 & C14 data as the file name
2. Save this PDF to my local G Drive (folder VBA work).

My macro completes step 1 above OK, but then no pdf file is appearing on my G:\VBA work folder.

Thoughts?

Once I get this going I need to write code to loop through data and repeat this step over and over, but that's next task once I get this going.

Thanking you...

```
Sub saveaspdftodrive()

    Dim SaveAsStr As String

    SaveAsStr = "G:\VBA work" & ActiveSheet.Range("C7") & ActiveSheet.Range("C14").Value

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=x1TypePDF, _
        Filename:=SaveAsStr & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _                                                                                                                              
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Type:=x1TypePDF` that should be `Type:=xlTypePDF` (l not 1)

Comment: Darn it, another example where `Option Explicit` saves the day!

Comment: For the line : SaveAsStr = "G:\VBA work" & ActiveSheet.Range("C7") & ActiveSheet.Range("C14"), does C7 begin with a backslash? Does C14 begin with a dot? Otherwise you're addressing a file G:\VBA workblabla. Look in the root folder of G:

Comment: Ah! Got it working. Thanks guys. Both tweaks in and now on my way...